# AngularJS Services API. Do not load the title tag when sharing the link

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, api

I need help completing a project. I'm having a problem loading the tags into the HTML HEAD with angularjs.

The problem I believe is that when I share a link the thefts in WhatsApp, Facebook and etc, do not load the AngularJS and thus do not load the data of the variable, thus showing only the "source code".

Correct:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imjZV.jpg)

Wrong:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCZ3I.jpg)

Version: AngularJS v1.6.1

Code html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ecApp" ng-controller="ecCtlr">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
      <meta name="fragment" content="!">
      <title>{{produto.nome}}</title>
      <meta name="description" content="{{produto.texto_descricao}}" />
      <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
      <script src="factory.js"></script>
      <script>
        var idLoja = 858;
        function carregaScope() {
          var scope = angular.element($('#ecCtlr')).scope();
          scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.buscaProduto(670706);
          });
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="carregaScope();" id="ecCtlr">
    </body>
</html>
```

Angular APP:

```
var api = 'http://localhost/api/';
var app = angular.module('ecApp', []);

app.controller('ecCtlr', function ($scope, $sce, ECProdutos) {

    $scope.buscaProduto = function(idProduto) {
        ECProdutos.buscaProduto(idLoja, idProduto).then(function (produto) {
            $scope.produto = produto;
            $scope.produtoPai = produto;
        });
    };
});
```

Factory:

```
angular.module("ecApp").factory("ECProdutos", function ($q, $http) {
    var urlClass = 'ec/produto/';
    return {
        buscaProduto: function (idLoja, idProduto) {
            var promessa = $q.defer();

            $http.get(api + '' + urlClass + 'buscaProduto/' + idLoja + '/' + idProduto).then(
                function (result) {
                    promessa.resolve(result.data);
                }
            );

            return promessa.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: 1) Where is your code? 2) Since we can't see your code, we don't know if you're using Angular1 or 2 since you mentioned both in your question... So it will be very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: @HunterTurner Edited, thank you

Answer (score 1):

i found this links... Cannot be resolved in angularjs:

http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app

https://rck.ms/angular-handlebars-open-graph-facebook-share/

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp and Facebook crawlers don't run JavaScript code on your page(yet :-)),

I prefer the following solution: host two html pages on your backend server, first page is the social-sharing slave, and the other is the *target page*.

First page: 
this page is the social-sharing 'slave', let's call it fromWhatsAppOrFacebook.html. It has hard coded properties for the social sharing: page title, description, preview images etc', all of them *hard coded*. And it has a tiny script which redirects the user to the Second page (for example, using the following command: window.location='second-page.html').

Second page: this page is the *target page*, its built with your AngularJS code or any other framework code base, the user is being redirected to this page from the 'First page' (or fromWhatsAppOrFacebook.html).

Hope it helps!!